# Does passing multiple devices to a context, mean kernels will be distributed to both devices?

Tags: c++, opencl

I've been writing some basic OpenCL programs and running them on a single device. I have been timing the performance of the code, to get an idea of how well each program is performing.

I have been looking at getting my kernels to run on the platforms GPU device, and CPU device at the same time. The cl::context constructor can be passed a std::vector of devices, to initialise a context with multiple devices. I have a system with a single GPU and a single CPU.

Is constructing a context with a vector of available devices all you have to do for kernels to be distributed to multiple devices? I noticed a significant performance increase when I did construct the context with 2 devices, but it seems too simple.

There is a DeviceCommandQueue object, perhaps I should be using that to create a queue for each device explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some testing on my system. Indeed you can do something like this:

```c
using namespace cl;
Context context({ devices[0], devices[1] });
queue = CommandQueue(context); // queue to push commands for the device, however do not specify which device, just hand over the context
Program::Sources source;
string kernel_code = get_opencl_code();
source.push_back({ kernel_code.c_str(), kernel_code.length() });
Program program(context, source);
program.build("-cl-fast-relaxed-math -w");
```

I found that if the two devices are from different platforms (like one Nvidia GPU and one Intel GPU), either `clCreateContext` will throw read access violation error at runtime or `program.build` will fail at runtime. If however the two devices are from the same platform, the code will compile and run; but it won't run on both devices. I tested with an Intel i7-8700K CPU and its integraed Intel UHD 630 GPU, and no matter the order of the devices in the vector that `context` is created on, the code will always be executed on the CPU in this case. I checked with Windows Task-Manager and also the results from kernel execution time measurement (execution times are specific for each device).

You could also monitor device usage with some tool like Task-Manager to see which device is actually running. Let me know if it is any different on your system than what I observed.

Generally parallelization across multiple devices is **not** done by handing the context a vector of devices, but instead you give each device a dedicated `context` and `queue` and explicitely handle which kernels are executed on which queue. This gives you full control on memory transfers and execution order / synchronization points.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing a performance increase when passing in the vector of devices. I downloaded a CPU/GPU profiler to actually check the activity of my GPU and CPU while I was running the code and it seemed that I was seeing activity on both devices. The CPU was registering around 95-100% activity, and the GPU was getting up to 30-40%, so OpenCL must be splitting the kernels between the 2 devices.  My computer has a CPU with an integrated GPU, which may play a role in why the kernels are being shared across the devices, because its not like it has a CPU and a completely seperate GPU, they're connected on the same component.